# By adding a finite number of sets to the set sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the limit superior doesn't change.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I have to prove that:

By adding a finite number of sets to the set sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the limit superior doesn't change.

I constructed a new sequence $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by adding the set $A$ to the sequnce $(A_n)$. That is $$E_1=A,\; E_2=A_1,\; \ldots,\; E_n=A_{n-1},\; \ldots$$ 
I have to prove that $$\lim\sup E_n=\lim\sup A_n$$
By definition:
$$\lim\sup E_n= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k$$
$$\lim\sup A_n= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$

We have that:
\begin{align*}
&\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k=E_n\cup E_{n+1}\cup \ldots=A_{n-1}\cup A_n\cup\ldots  \\
& \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=A_n\cup A_{n+1}\cup \ldots \\
\Longrightarrow & \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\\
\Longrightarrow& \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\\
\Longrightarrow & \lim\sup A_n \subseteq \limsup E_n
\end{align*}
Now I want to prove that $$\lim\sup E_n \subseteq \limsup A_n$$
So I took a random $x\in \lim\sup E_n$. That means 
\begin{align*}
(\forall n\in \mathbb{N}) \; x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k & \Leftrightarrow x\in E_n \cup E_{n+1} \cup \ldots \\
& \Leftrightarrow x\in A_{n-1}\cup A_n \cup \ldots \\
& \Leftrightarrow x\in \bigcup_{k=n-1}^\infty A_k
\end{align*}

Now I have somehow to imply from here that $x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$, but that's where I have a problem, because for $n=1$ I have that 
$$x\in \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty A_k=A_0\cup A_1 \cup \ldots$$
What if $x\in A_0$, then I can't say that $x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$. So if anyone has a good idea what to do, please.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\in\limsup E_n$. Let's prove that for every $n$ there exists $k>n$ such that $x\in A_k$. Given $n$, there exists $k>n+1$ such that $x\in E_k=A_{k-1}$ (because $x\in\limsup E_n$). Since $k-1>n$, we have that $x\in\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, we deduce that $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$. This proves that $\limsup E_n\subset \limsup A_n$.

Comment: Why is $k>n$, and not $k\geq n$?

Comment: Because $k>n+1$. If you give me $n$, I use the fact that $x$ belongs to the union of $A_k$'s when $k$ starts from any $n$, and in particular from $n+1$.

Comment: So, the situation that $x\in A_0$ that I came across isn't possible?

Comment: It is possible, but $A_0$ would not be the only $A_k$ that has $x$ in it.

Comment: In your previous comment, did you mean that $x$ belongs to the union of $E_k$'s or?

Comment: Yes, I did. I mistakenly wrote $A_k$ instead of $E_k$.

Answer (score 0):

The limsup of the sequence of sets $A_n$ is the set of all $x$ in $X$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ with $x \in A_n$. This is often an easier way of thinking about it. This follows directly from the formulaic definition if you think about it a little.

Adding finitely many sets to the sequence doesn't change those $x$. That's the whole proof in a nutshell.